# dynamic change in layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility, expandablelistview, android-gridview

I have a few elements-arranged like this in the same order:
textview, textview, slider bar, button,gridview,button, gridview, button.
I toggle the gridview's visibility when the button above it is clicked. Earlier I had faced the problem of the gridview hiding everything that came below it and so I assigned weights to the buttons but the gridview(although scrollable) looks very scrunched up. How can I increase the width of the gridview so that the elements below that maintain their relative positions and appear where they should.(I want the behaviour of an expandable list when I click on the button basically)

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"        
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="Select Price Range"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/seekBar_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:padding="10dip"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/absMinMax_holder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/absMinCarVal"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/absMaxCarVal_above"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/minMax_holder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="40dip"
            android:paddingRight="40dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/minVal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/absMinCarVal"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value_seperator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/value_seperator"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/maxVal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/absMaxCarVal"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
<!--    <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> -->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" > 

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/car_make"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Car Make"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


             <GridView 
                android:id="@+id/make_gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>                            

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/car_models"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Car Models"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

            <GridView 
                android:id="@+id/models_gridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>        

        </LinearLayout>
    <!-- </ScrollView>   -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you use tableLayout instead and make rows of the table `gone` and `visible` as required. This would give the effect of expandable list. Please feel free to ask any doubts

Comment: No,' this doesn't help. I can't have a table layout since my data is not static.

Comment: I had implemented it with dynamic data. You can create table and add data programmatically

Comment: I had done the same and have the code but it might be tough to digest as it has some other functionalities as well so have not posted it. The concept is simple and easy to implement. I have some Db access and there are two expandable lists out of which only 1 is shown according to the user choice ( radio btn) , so my code is a bit lengthy, that is why I haven't posted it